# Can I make low (or no) protein beer?

Tags: brewing

Beer has some protein in it from the grains used (and maybe other ingredients), does anyone know if I can make a beer with little to no protein?

Answer (score 1):

Proteins are essential for yeast growth.  However, a typical finished beer only has around a half gram of protein per 12 oz. serving - which is pretty minimal, but also pretty much unavoidable.

http://www.homebrewtalk.com/f128/introduction-protein-structure-111819/

Why is it a concern?

Comment: I know people who have PKU, which is a genetic disorder that makes people unable to process one of the amino acids in protein, so they are VERY limited in how much protein they can have. I wanted to make them a beer that they could enjoy without having to worry about the protein level.

Comment: Well, sadly, I don't think a protein-free beer is possible, but there are a few ways to limit the quantities and types of protein: lower-protein malts, a protein rest (if brewing all-grain) to break down larger proteins, and lighter, lower-strength beers, which will have a lower concentration of proteins.

Hope that helps!